# cvc-elt.1.a:, Can not find the declaration of element 'persistence'

Tags: xml, hibernate, jpa

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" 
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
                                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">


    <persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"     value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=SocialDB"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="ramy"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="%=4b[E6c"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And here is the error:

```
Root Cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.

org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:147)
org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:171)
org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:326)
org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:58)
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
bo.MyEntityManagerFactory.getEntityManager(MyEntityManagerFactory.java:22)
bo.UserHandler.getAllUsers(UserHandler.java:106)
bo.UserHandler.getAllUserViewsTrimmed(UserHandler.java:88)
```

I receive this error once upon starting the server as well as each time I perform a database query.

Edit:
Here are my (Maven) dependencies (The project is a web microservice that interfaces with an MSSQL database using Hibernate, and uses jersey framework to convert from/to JSON object in order to read to/write from the aforementioned database):

```
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-web-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.asm</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
            
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, Saxon (running from the command line) reports your instance document as valid. So it's not an intrinsic problem with the XML document or schema, it's some kind of configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can not think of any configurations that might have something wrong. Especially that everything else is working properly.

Comment: Besides, when I edit the XML to make it malfunctional on a purpose I get the error message that I would expect.